# How to change an instance variable of all instances of a class at once, Java

Tags: java, class, static, instance, non-static

I want to have multiple instances of a class, but be able to change all non-static instances of a variable at once. Maybe this code will be more clear:

```
public class Example {
     public int _x; //_x and _y are NOT static
     public int _y;
     Example (int x, int y) {
     _x = x;
     _y = y;
     }
     public void zeroThem() {
     _x = 0;
     _y = 0;
     }
}
```

The point of the `zeroThem()` method is that I might have

```
Example A = new Example(1, 2);
Example B = new Example(3, 4);
```

But once I call something like:
`A.zeroThem();`
The following will be true:

```
A._x == 0;
B._x == 0;
A._y == 0;
B._y == 0;
```

Is there any way to do this without making _x and _y static?

Comment: Yes if you have your objects in a collection then you can loop over that collection (or use streams) and zero all objects.

Comment: This design doesn't seem right. Is this your real problem or are you trying to achieve something else and this is just a demo? If so, maybe adding some real context may help us to better help you.

Comment: Maybe you should have made the field `static` in the first place, if this is how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the help of the following fixes:

1. Your instance variables need to be `volatile`
2. You need to have static *synchronized* collection of `Example` instances and iterate it.
3. According to your request, you need to have method `zeroAll` calling instance method `zeroThem`.  `zeroAll` may be implemented as non-static, but as soon as it affects *all* instances of `Example` it's better to mark it as `static`.

```
public class Example {

    private static List<Example> all = Collections.synchronizedList(
        new ArrayList<>());

    public volatile int _x; //_x and _y are NOT static
    public volatile int _y;

    Example (int x, int y) {
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
        Example.all.add(this);
    }

    public void zeroThem() {
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
    }

    public static void zeroAll() {
        synchronized(Example.all) {
            Example.all.forEach(Example::zeroThem);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
Addressing comment to resolve memory leak issue using `WeakReference` and `ReferenceQueue`:

```
import java.lang.ref.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Example {

    private static final ReferenceQueue<Example> refQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    private static final List<WeakReference<Example>> all = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    public volatile int _x; //_x and _y are NOT static
    public volatile int _y;

    Example (int x, int y) {
        this._x = x;
        this._y = y;
        Example.all.add(new WeakReference<>(this, refQueue));
    }

    public void zeroThem() {
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
    }

    public static void zeroAll() {
        synchronized(Example.all) {
            Example.all.removeIf(ref -> ref.get() == null); // delete non-existing instances
            Example.all
                .stream()
                .map(WeakReference::get)
                .forEach(Example::zeroThem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You require the OP to make the instance variables volatile but then use a non thread safe collection is instances at the class level - this makes very little sense. Without something rather sophisticated - a `ReferenceQueue` - what you’ve built here is a memory leak.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, you've been right, thanks for pointing out these issues.  I updated the answer to address your comments.